# SwiftUI VStack Alignment Bug?

Tags: swift, swiftui, alignment, vstack

I've been building an application in SwiftUI recently and today I'm noticing that the VStack Alignment is having some strange behavior. No matter the alignment I use, the view isn't aligning outside of the center. See below:

```
VStack(alignment: .trailing, spacing: 0) {
    Text("Hello, World!")
}
```

[image]

```
VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 0) {
    Text("Hello, World!")
}
```

[image: sw]

It's doing this in both the preview and the simulator, I'm trying to align my text to the right edge of the screen.

Full Code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct DemoView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 0) {
            Text("Hello, World!")
        }
    }
}

struct DemoView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        DemoView()
    }

}
```

Comment: That's not a bug. SwiftUI parent view is the same size as its child view if you don't specify size to the parent view.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The `VStack(alignment:...)` is for aligning subviews, but you have only one subview, so nothing to align

By default all stacks are tight to content (just add .border to your test VStack/s and you see the result, so there is no area to move content.

What you expected is solved by giving frame alignment in stack providing screen-wide area:

[image: demo]

```
VStack {
    Text("Hello, World!")
}.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .trailing)
```

P.S. SwiftUI still has many bugs, but not here :)

Answer (score 6):

I agree with the author, the behavior is strange...at least.
Alignment for VStack subviews does not work in case:

```
VStack(alignment: .leading) {
    Text("Hello, world!")
    Text("Hello, world!")
}
.frame(width: 200, height: 200)
```

but works in case:

```
VStack {
    Text("Hello, world!")
    Text("Hello, world!")
}
.frame(width: 200, height: 200, alignment: .leading)
```

If this is not a bug then definitively a poor realisation of the "declarative" approach.